# PHP duplicate row

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

[this is what i intended to insert to my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxpw3.png)

this is the code for inserting errors.

```
         <tr>
        <form method="POST" id="myform" action="">
        <td></td>
        <td><?php echo strtoupper($row2['lrn']); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo ucwords($fullname);?></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="attendance"  name="attendance[2]"  value="0"> </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="" class="af" disabled=""></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="quiz1[]" class="quiz" value="0"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="quiz1[]" class="quiz" value="0"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="quiz1[]" class="quiz" value="0"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="quiz1[]" class="quiz" value="0" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="quiz1[]" class="quiz" value="0" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="" class="qf" disabled=""></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="" class="recitation11" value="0"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="" class="recitation11" value="0"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="" class="recitation11" value="0"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="" class="recitation11" value="0"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="" class="recitation11" value="0"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="" class="rf11" disabled=""></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="" class="seatwork11" value="0"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="" class="seatwork11" value="0"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="" class="seatwork11" value="0"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="" class="seatwork11" value="0"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="" class="seatwork11" value="0"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="" class="swf11" disabled=""></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="" class="project11" value="0"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="" class="project11" value="0"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="" class="project11" value="0"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="" class="pf11" disabled=""></td>
        <td style="text-align: center"><input  type="text" name="" class="fg60" disabled=""></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="student[]" value="<?php echo $id3;?>"></td>
            <?php

          if(isset($_POST['submitgrades'])) {


                      foreach((array)$_POST['student'] as $student1)
                      { 

                     foreach ((array)$_POST['attendance'] as $attendance2) {   
                        $attendance3 = implode(",", (array)$attendance2);
                     $attendancequery = "SELECT * FROM gradesheet_tbl WHERE studentID = '$student1' OR attendance = '$attendance3'";
                     $attendanceresult = mysqli_query($con, $attendancequery);
                 }
                     if(mysqli_num_rows($attendanceresult)>0){

                     }  
                     else{


                        $grades = "INSERT INTO gradesheet_tbl (sectionID, studentID, jrhteacherID, attendance) 
                        VALUES ('$id2','$student1','$teacherID','$attendance3')";
                        $gradesresult = mysqli_query($con, $grades);
                        if($gradesresult){
                           echo "<script>alert('Success')</script>";
                            }
                else{
                              echo "<script>alert('failed')</script>";
                }
            }

             }   
                  }       











            ?>                
    </tr>


    <?php }
    } ?>
```

-the problem is the rows is duplicated 3x.much appreciated.
please help us to find the error because we are still noob at php.
we are still debugging this error until yesterday. What i wanted to insert in my database is in the picture.

Comment: So you get data inserted into the database but it's inserted 3 times instead once? Your code is also open to SQL injection. You must use mysqli prepared statement with parameters. Your INSERT query is also in foreach, so that might be the problem.